# How do I get rid of this ERROR 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Honestly, I don't understand why I have this error. Someone can help, please?

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p foodly < /Users/gregoireperney/Documents/1-dev/trainings_no_git/sql_foodly_db/partie_2/foodly.sql;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p foodly < /Users/gregoireperney/Documents/1-dev/trainings_no_git' at line 1
```

(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for osx11.1 (x86_64), Server version: 8.3.0 Homebrew)

I have tried to search for an answer in the manual, but it was unsuccessful.

This is the beginning of the file code, maybe it's because of that:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.21, for osx10.15 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: foodly2
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.21
```

Comment: `mysql>` is not a shell command-line, it's a SQL command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entering a command in the MySQL prompt, which only accepts SQL statements. You need to exit the MySQL command-line client and enter the command in your system terminal.

Comment: Ok that's it. Thanks, I didn't know and this so obvious that nobody mentioned it on other posts.